# Unity3D objects creating

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new in Unity3D. How can I creating objects, in example, spheres during the game?
I'm found this JavaScript code:

```
     var projectile : Rigidbody;
     var speed = 20;

     function Update()
     {
             if( Input.GetKeyDown( KeyCode.Mouse0 ) )
             {
                     var instantiatedProjectile : Rigidbody = Instantiate( projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation );
                     instantiatedProjectile.velocity = transform.TransformDirection( Vector3( 0, 0, speed ) ); 
                     Physics.IgnoreCollision( instantiatedProjectile. collider, transform.root.collider );
             }
     }
```

Will this script create object, that will be moving? Suppose this script is that I need, that I need to do with it after? When I was programming movement of sphere I attached script to my sphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it instantiate rigibodies by clicking 0 in keyboard. And collision doesnt detect

For more information go through

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreCollision.html

Comment: That object I must to attach this script?

Comment: which object? projectile? projectile u have to attach in inspector